# Dedicated, shorter domain for vanity careers URLs

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Right now we've got a public vanity URL on Careers (mine is `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/blixt`) that's pretty long.

It'd be nice if [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) had some kind of shorter version of its URL that redirects you to the longer version.
Much like Flickr has `http://flic.kr/mr-blixt`

Mostly wishful thinking from my part I guess =)

Answer (score 3):

If you had a shortened version of the site, you'd lose the cachet that automatically comes from an easy glance of the current version of your vanity URL.

It's got both Careers and Stack Overflow and shows that you mean business about your career.

Shrink that down into something a few characters long, what are you ashamed of?

Comment: Maybe it'd be good for those who like showing off links on that Twitter bandwagon.

Comment: I didn't mean it should be short just for the sake of being short (so not something silly like http://bit.ly/3aW01W). The purpose would be to have a URL that's to-the-point, easy to type/remember and fits well in various documents (I like URLs that are about as long as my e-mail address =)

Answer (score 1):

One option is an abbreviated domain such as

**socareers.com**/blitxt (currently available)

a bit shorter and expressive enough for those 'in the know'

But then again this also says "So, careers?" >D

Comment: Well I think meaning is more important than abbreviation... It doesn't necessarily need to be all that attached to SO (although it's a plus if it is, considering the flair part of the CV.) There are plenty of fun things you can do with short domains... http://hello-i.am/blixt http://caree.rs/blixt (taken, but maybe buyable) etc.

Comment: giveajobto.me is available too :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an alias to your own domain that redirect to SO careers. So, if you have `blixt.com`, `blixt.com/cv/` would redirect to careers.

Comment: I'd tend to host my CV in my format on my site though...